# Freezing Movement to the side after rotating GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to freeze the position of a GameObject towards the z-Axis but when turning the GameObject the z-Axis should turn with it (or atleast the freeze Position)

So basically I want my object to only be able to move forward, backwards and up and down, no matter what direction it is facing.

A RigidBody freeze Position is in relation to the world axis and not the rotated axis of the object.

Appreciate the help, thank you

[Top Down View of Object, before rotation and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFcbc.png)

Comment: Where is your code? How are you moving the object?

Comment: I am moving it with phsyics, rigidbody and a slope in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the GameObject's "z-axis" with `transform.forward`. If this isn't the axis you want, try `transform.right` or `transform.up`.

It's unclear what you're asking for. Here are two cases that might answer your question:

To confine velocity to the "z-axis":

```
//reference to the Rigidbody to restrict
private Rigidbody rig;
void Start(){
    //find the Rigidbody attached to this GameObject
    rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

//Updates every physics frame
void FixedUpdate(){
    //set the velocity to the component of the velocity that is parallel to the forward direction
    rig.velocity = transform.forward * Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, rig.velocity);
}
```

If you don't want any movement in the "z-axis", replace the `rig.velocity = ...` line with `rig.velocity -= ...`

Put this code in a MonoBehaviour (script) attached to your GameObject.

Note that if the GameObject is physically hit, it might spin, causing the "z-axis" to rapidly change. To prevent this, you could use the Rigidbody freeze rotation.

Comment: Thank you, this is working as expected.